# Publishing javadoc automatically when building a maven project with hudson

Tags: maven-2, hudson, javadoc

I'm using Hudson to build Maven-projects with the dedicated Maven 2 job. unfortunately, I can't find any way to publish the generated javadoc like it can be done using a "Free Style" job and the "Publish javadoc" option. Running the javadoc goal didn't link the generated javadocs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, that in your POM you need to define javadoc as a report like this:

```
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

There is no need to switch to freestyle project. After it, hudson will publish it as a link in project view. My Hudson version is 1.376.

Comment: +1 It works for me, if a add the goals javadoc:javadoc and site:site

Answer (score 2):

i'm using `javadoc:aggregate` and Hudson will recognize it. Actually it is equivalent to `javadoc:javadoc` AND `site:site` as `javadoc:aggregate` generates reporting too.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/plugin-info.html

Answer (score 1):

What we do:

- Use `-DperformRelease` in the Maven options to generate the `...-javadoc.jar`
- Create and deploy a Maven site which includes the javadoc.

Comment: I'm using Hudson to build non-Maven projects too and would like the javadoc to be linked on the job page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best I could do was switching to a "Free Style" job...the Maven job isn't doing that much for me anyways.